# SQL SUM counting every instance and not if data is present

Tags: sql, null, sum

I have a piece of a SQL statement below:

```
SELECT WOCUSTFIELD.WORKORDERID, WORKORDER.ACTUALFINISHDATE, 
       CASE WHEN  wocustfield.custfieldname LIKE '%bags%'
              THEN (REPLACE( wocustfield.custfieldname, 'bags:', '')) 
            ELSE REPLACE( wocustfield.custfieldname, 'boxes:', '')
       END AS Facility,
```

For each of the custfieldname that has a number > than 0 put in for Bags or Boxes I would like to count it as a Facility (visit to teh site).
Currently, it is counting every custfieldname regardless if it has a number ( 0 or >) in the field as a visit and is totaling all custfieldnames for each day.
for example, if the data look like the following for Jan 1st 2023:

```
                 Bags     Boxes
Dogstation 1        3        4
Dogstation 2        0        0
Dogstation 3        5        1
Dogstation 4        2        0
Dogstation 5        0        0
```

I would like to have 3 Facility (visits) stations and not 5.  I hope this makes sense.  thanks for any help given

Comment: Can you show what the original table looks like? If that data is the source table, why not just query for `SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE Bags>0 OR Boxes>0`?

Answer (score 1):

Just add in a `WHERE` clause. I'm not exactly sure how your table is formatted, but ex:
`WHERE Bags>0 OR Boxes>0`

Comment: Had the same though when I read the need of data presence: why not filter `NULL`s then? Welcome SO @hduperier

Answer (score 1):

The COUNT aggregation counts 1 for every non-null. Zero (0) is not null, so it will count as 1. You want to do something like this:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN bags >0 then 1 else 0 end) as stores_with_bags
```